# I have to delete exports file every time I use vagrant up

Tags: vagrant, nfs

After upgrading to MacOS Catalina, I was unable to use NFS for quite some time. Recently, I discovered the issue was that I needed to grant both VirtualBox and nfsd full disk access in my privacy preferences. Since then, I've been able to use vagrant to control my VMs again. However, NFS always reports that my /etc/exports file is invalid every time I use vagrant up/reload for any of my VMs.

> NFS is reporting that your exports file is invalid. Vagrant does
>   this check before making any changes to the file. Please correct
>   the issues below and execute "vagrant reload":
>
> exports:3: /System/Volumes/Data/Users/myuser/Projects/mysite.dev/sites conflicts with existing export /System/Volumes/Data/Users/myuser/Projects/mysite.dev

The contents of my exports file looks like this:

```
# VAGRANT-BEGIN: 501 3fabdc3e-226a-4a42-8eef-390d50d9052f
/System/Volumes/Data/Users/myuser/Projects/mysite.dev -alldirs -mapall=501:20 192.168.100.101
/System/Volumes/Data/Users/myuser/Projects/mysite.dev/sites -alldirs -mapall=501:20 192.168.100.101
# VAGRANT-END: 501 3fabdc3e-226a-4a42-8eef-390d50d9052f
```

I only mount the sites directory in the vagrant config, not the mysite.dev directory And I'm using DrupalVM. 
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A few of my colleagues and I were running into this issue as well. Here's the Github issue so you can keep track: https://github.com/geerlingguy/drupal-vm/issues/2019.